# Dynamic Property creation in .net from Column-Names of Table

Tags: .net, object, .net-4.0, code-generation, dynamic-data

My current Scenario is, I manually create a property FirstName(of a Class Student) in .cs file and assign it to the Column name First_Name . 
i.e. I have to manually write the Properties(private variables, Public Properties and Getters and Setters).
Then I retrieve the Table from Database and get its column-name(First_Name) and assign it to FirstName property. I have to write thousands of line on cs file for property creation.

My requirement is, I need to automate the Property creation part and dynamically generate it.
For eg. if the Column name is First_Name then create a property FirstName(by truncating the UnderScores). This will save a lot of codeWriting and Debugging Time for me.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you looked at tools like ORMs? Most of those include the ability to generate classes from your existing database...

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for an ORM (Entity Framework, NHibernate, ...). Apart from that, there is quite a lot of information about code generation on the internet, just search for it (admittedly, there is a lot of information, and maybe hard to actually get to a solution).

Comment: @MarcGravell: you were saying something about usage of ExpandObject, you deleted it. Was it an Unethical solution ??

Comment: @LetsKickSomeAssin.net no, I just re-read your question and it looked like you were after **classes**. ExpandoObject is not a way to create classes.